# toggle visibility of a Layer in Openlayers 3(!) with a Checkbox

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-2, html, visibility

I have some vector layers on top of a tiled layer and a checkbox for each vector layer. I want a layer to be visible if its checkbox is checked and vanish if it gets unchecked.

I tried to call a function with the *onchange* attribute of the checkbox. It should set the visibility of the layer according to the (un)checked state of the checkbox.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/vqc556yp/) is my fiddle but unfortunately the checkboxes don't change anything.

edit: updated the code..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call setVisibility(true/false) on the layer.

[setVisibility](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.layer.Layer.html#setVisible)

All you are doing in your code is changing the value of static variables. This will not trigger any action on the layer.

In your checkbox handler, you need to get a reference to the layer and change the visibility:

```
triangleLayer1.setVisible(value);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried as you said. Did I do something wrong? Please see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vqc556yp/1/) Oh and I think your link is an API for Openlayers 2 or something..

Comment: well I looked for a similiar function in OL3 and there is! Please change your link to `http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.layer.Layer.html#setVisible` and the code to `triangleLayer1.setVisible(value);` so that I can accept the answer

Comment: Note also that you can set the `visible` property in the `options` object supplied when you create the layer - details can be found at the documentation link listed above